# Rails Route Redirecting to different view by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :admin do
    post 'user_creation', on: :collection
  end
  get 'admin/user_creation'
  resources :admin, :only => [:user_creation, :create, :new]
 end
```

the following is my controller

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new
  end
  def create
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new(dashboard_params)
    @dashboard_user.save!
  end
  def user_creation

  end
  private
  def dashboard_params
  params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:user_name, :password, :last_name, :first_name, :middle_name , :phone)
  end
end
```

then its a simple .html.erb file
what happens is that when i try to open the link admin/user_creation it automatically redirects to show.html.erb file

rake routes output

```
rake routes
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
user_creation_admin_index POST   /admin/user_creation(.:format) admin#user_creation
              admin_index GET    /admin(.:format)               admin#index
                          POST   /admin(.:format)               admin#create
                new_admin GET    /admin/new(.:format)           admin#new
               edit_admin GET    /admin/:id/edit(.:format)      admin#edit
                    admin GET    /admin/:id(.:format)           admin#show
                          PATCH  /admin/:id(.:format)           admin#update
                          PUT    /admin/:id(.:format)           admin#update
                          DELETE /admin/:id(.:format)           admin#destroy
      admin_user_creation GET    /admin/user_creation(.:format) admin#user_creation
                          POST   /admin(.:format)               admin#create
                          GET    /admin/new(.:format)           admin#new
                     root GET    /                              admin#new
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route not looking good. Whenever we try to go to any url directly from browser it consider request as `get` type. routes file try to find route from top to bottom. That why it's considering `/admin/user_creation` as show action of `admin_controller` and `user_creation` as id to show.

Don't know why you need get and post request for same action. But your routes should look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :admin, :only => [:create, :new] do
    post 'user_creation', on: :collection
    get 'user_creation', on: :collection
  end
end
```

One thing with above routes there is no route for show action. Now you will properly go to user_creation path.

if you don't need any post path then it should look like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :admin, :only => [:create, :new] do
    get 'user_creation', on: :collection
  end
end
```

if you need all the default action then:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :admin do
    get 'user_creation', on: :collection
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are clicking the link for the url. `admin/user_creation`
But your route says it is a POST url .

It need to added as GET.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :admin do
    post 'user_creation', on: :collection
    get 'user_creation', on: :collection
  end
  get 'admin/user_creation'
  resources :admin, :only => [:user_creation, :create, :new]
 end
```

Comment: i am trying to post data and then redirect it to the same page  so i should use post right?

Comment: Yes, if you are using the both then you need to declare both post, get